# How to add netbeans (9) predefined maven actions to netbeans toolbar?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-platform, netbeans-9

I have a question that I think I should know the answer to, but don't.

Netbeans maven support has a list of predefined actions. I can't seem to figure out how to get them placed on the toolbar without writing a plugin :-

Please help..  what am I missing?

thanks

Comment: Is this Netbeans 8 or 9 (tag or title)?

Comment: This is netbeans 9..  I can add actions to the context menu using settings.xml, but it not the toolbar..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late to the party but anyway... If you mean actions global to your NB installation (not related to a specific project), go to:

Tools | Options | Java | Maven | Edit Global Custom Goal Definitions...

There you can define an action and click "Show in Toolbar" and assign it an icon, which will then appear on the Build toolbar. Unfortunately, there are only six icons to choose from. If anybody knows how to add more (without manually changing the NB's resource jar files), please let us all know.